# After updating gradle, the program gives an error when running

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I get this error while running the project

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/aliazizi/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-8.0.9/android/local.properties'.

Comment: The error message exactly tells you what to do, so have you modified the `local.properties` fiel just as the error message suggests?

Comment: @Robert This file does not exist in this path!